# Javascript multidimension arrays

Tags: javascript

I am creating a chat application and I ran into scaling issues. I want to create an array "roomspace" which holds multiple "room" and each room holds multiple "users". I can obviously hard code this thing but for the scale of scaling I need to declare something like roomspace[][]. But I am not being able to declare in this way and also i have been running problems while traversing the array. Can someone please give me a sample of how can this be accomplished. I would really appreciate that.

Comment: So you have a 2D array. So you can declare it by `roomspace=[]`. `roomspacee.push([])` to add a new "room". The you can use for loops like `for (var i = 0; i < roomspace[room].length; i++){ /* stuff */}` to go through a `room`. Is that okay?

Comment: assuming rooms and users are also arrays,
var roomspace = [];
//add new room//
roomspace[roomspace.length] = [];
//delete room,offset lets say 1//
delete roomspace[1];
//add user to room, lets say to room 0//
roomspace[0][roomspace[0].length] = [];

Comment: Have you concidered using JSON? I belive that would be nice in your case.

Comment: Thanx man, I shall look at it..

Answer (score 1):

Here is a small model for you. I made the `roomSpace` an object in which you can access the room by name than index.

Also you have the constructor for room object which knows how to handle a room

And the last loop demonstrates how you can traverse through the entire `roomSpace`.

You can add any number of rooms and any number of users to it dynamically. You can scale this model up by adding more methods and properties.

```
//Your room space
var roomSpace = {};    


//This function returns a room object
function constructRoom() {
    return {                
                users: [],        
                addUser: function(userName) {
                    this.users.push(userName);
                },

                clearUsers: function() {
                    this.users = {};
                }    
            }
}     



//Here you add rooms    
roomSpace['javascript'] = constructRoom();
roomSpace['php'] = constructRoom();

//Add some users
roomSpace['javascript'].addUser('charlie');
roomSpace['php'].addUser('john');


//Clear the whole room space of users
for (var room in roomSpace) {
  roomSpace[room].clearUsers();
}
```

Comment: Thank You Charlie, How can I traverse through users?

Comment: You can traverse through users by `roomSpace[roomName].users[n]`